# Mapping RestKit Post Response

Tags: objective-c, ios, mapping, restkit

I am posting to a uri using RestKit

```
    NSString* path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"myPathHere"];
    NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithKeysAndObjects:@"rating",[rating stringValue], nil];
   [[RKObjectManager sharedManager].client post:path params:params delegate:self];
```

The server will respond with an updated version of my managedObject "Item".

How do I go about mapping this item. Do I use the following delegate method?

```
- (void)request:(RKRequest *)request didLoadResponse:(RKResponse *)response{}
```

I know that from here I can get the response JSON value but how do I change that into the mapped object?

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I've needed to map my server objects I make the request like this:

```
        [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] 
         loadObjectsAtResourcePath:[qualifiedResourceURL
                                    appendQueryParams:params] 
         delegate:self  
         ];
```

and then the object comes back in this method:

```
    - (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader*)objectLoader didLoadObjects:(NSArray*)objects
```

I then post the updated object with the Notification Manager

```
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:GotFotosInRegion_Fotos_Array_Response object:objects];
```

The best documentation is at https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/blob/master/Docs/Object%20Mapping.md

Comment: This works if I was using GET but I am using POST. If you look at the method applyQueryParams all it is doing is taking your dictionary you pass in and appending it to the path with a "?" in the middle.

Comment: Can you setup your RKObjectRouter to is POST. Something like this:     router = [RKObjectRouter new] ;
    [router routeClass:[CheckStatus class] toResourcePath:@"/registration/rest/users/checkstatus" forMethod:RKRequestMethodPOST];

Comment: I've tried this and it doesn't seem to work. I feel like Im getting closer. The following *(in next comment)* will result in objectloader didloadobjects being called bu the objects array is empty.

Comment: `NSString* path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/PATH/HERE",theItem.entityId, theItem.identifier];

    RKObjectManager*objectManager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];
    RKObjectLoader* objectLoader = [objectManager objectLoaderWithResourcePath:path delegate:self];
    objectLoader.method = RKRequestMethodPOST;
    objectLoader.params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithKeysAndObjects:@"rating",[rating stringValue], nil];
    objectLoader.targetObject = self;
    objectLoader.objectMapping = [ObjectMappings mappingForMenu];
    [objectLoader send];`

Comment: ahh, then your mapping is wrong. Probably want to start a new question with that. Show us the mapping code AND your JSON.

Comment: Thanks Paul, you were right. I wasn't looking at my json closely enough and I actually getting something back that was only slightly different then what I expected.

Comment: that slightly will trip you up. Are you using a proxy? Charles Proxy saved me hours the day I installed it.